# changing option fetch data based on selection using

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two tab buttons - the first one is rent and second tab is buy.
If the user clicks the rent tab then search bar appears. The same field is available for both but if clicking rent tab then rent tab search bar active, and if click buy then show buy tab.

The default state after page load is the buy tab is active, and search bar, and if I click the rent buy tab then all fields of data fetch according to my code, but if I click the rent tab then the data is not fetched.

See below is the screenshot if clicking buy tab search bar data fetch

[image]

and second buy tab tab data fetch image

[image]

and see the rent tab select

[image]

and second rent tab data not fetch

[image]
here is the chrome debagging tool image if selecting rent

https://ibb.co/d72b28K

https://ibb.co/NFMpjj6

Here is the html code for both tabs

```
<!-- Home Design -->
  <section class="home-one home1-overlay bg-home1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row posr">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="home_content home1 custom_width">
            <div class="home-text text-center">
              <p class="fz18 color-white">It's great to be Property!</p>
              <h2 class="fz50">Find Your Perfect Property</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="home_tabs">
              <ul class="nav justify-content-center nav-tabs" id="myTab2" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="buy-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#buy" role="tab" aria-controls="buy" aria-selected="true">Buy</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="rent-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#rent" role="tab" aria-controls="rent" aria-selected="false">Rent</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <!-- test -->
              
              <!-- test -->
              <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent2">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="buy" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="buy-tab">
                  <div class="home_adv_srch_opt">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                      <div class="home_adv_srch_form">
                        <form method="POST" action="a_t_listing.php" class="bgc-white p20" id="searchform" name="searchform">
                          <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md">
                              <div class="form-group style2 mb-2 pl10 pl0-lg">
                                <label>TYPE</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style2-dropdown">
                                  <select class="selectpicker show-tick" name="property_type" id="property_type" >
                                    <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
                                    <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
                                 
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md">
                              <div class="form-group style2 mb-2 pl10 pl0-lg">
                                <label>LOCATION</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style2-dropdown">
                                  <select class="selectpicker" name="Locality" id="Locality" data-live-search="true">
                                  <!-- <option value="">All Cities / Areas</option> -->
                                  <!-- Data Load By Ajax Best Code Attache footer file -->
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md" style="">
                              <div class="form-group style1 mb-2 ml0-767">
                                <label id="search-lable">SEARCH</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style1-dropdown">
                                  <!-- <select name="searchQuery" class="form-control js-searchBox" id="searchQuery">
                                    <option value="">Endorse Property</option>
                                    <option value="TheBliss">The Bliss</option>
                                    <option value="CasaVyoma">Casa Vyoma</option>
                                    <option value="WorldTradeTower">World Trade Tower</option>
                                    <option value="Hotels">View All Results</option>
                                  </select> -->
                                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery" placeholder="Enter Locality / Project / Society / Landmark" autocomplete="off">
                                  <div id="suggestionContainer"></div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_adv_srch_form_btn mb20-md">
                              <div class="adv_srch_btn dropbtn ml0-767" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop" id="advance_search_mo">
                                <i class="flaticon-setting-lines mr10 mt10 mt0-md flr-520"></i>
                                <span id="advance-search">Advanced Search</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input2" id="home_form_input2">
                               <input type="hidden" name="tab" id="selectedTab" value="buy">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn search-btn ml0-767" id="search-btn"><span class="fa fa-search"></span> Search</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
    
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="rent" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="rent-tab">
                  <div class="home_adv_srch_opt">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                      <div class="home_adv_srch_form">
                        <form method="POST" action="a_t_listing.php" class="bgc-white p20" id="rent-form" name="searchform" >
                          <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md">
                              <div class="form-group style2 mb-2 pl10 pl0-lg">
                                <label>TYPE</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style2-dropdown">
                                  <select class="selectpicker show-tick" name="property_type" id="property_type" >
                                    <option value="Residentail">Residentail</option>
                                    <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
                                      
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md">
                              <div class="form-group style2 mb-2 pl10 pl0-lg">
                                <label>LOCATION</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style2-dropdown">
                                  <select class="selectpicker" name="Locality" id="Locality" data-live-search="true">
                                  <option value="">All Cities / Areas</option>
                                  <!-- Data Load By Ajax Best Code Attache footer file -->
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md">
                              <div class="form-group style1 mb-2 ml0-767">
                                <label>SEARCH</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style2-dropdown">
                                  <!-- <select name="lang" class="form-control js-searchBox">
                                    <option value="">Endorse Property</option>
                                    <option value="sankalpgrace2">Sankalp Grace 2</option>
                                    <option value="StratumVenus">Stratum Venus</option>
                                    <option value="Indraparasth6">Indraparasth 6</option>
                                    <option value="Hotels">View All Results</option>
                                  </select> -->
                                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery" placeholder="Enter Locality / Project / Society / Landmark" autocomplete="off">
                                  <div id="suggestionContainer"></div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_adv_srch_form_btn mb20-md">
                              <div class="adv_srch_btn dropbtn ml0-767" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
                                <i class="flaticon-setting-lines mr10 mt10 mt0-md flr-520"></i>
                                <span id="advance-search">Advanced Search</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input2">
                              <!-- Add a hidden input field to store the selected tab -->
                               <input type="hidden" name="tab" id="selectedTab" value="rent">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn search-btn ml0-767"><span class="fa fa-search"></span> Search</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

here is the my javacsript code for both tab

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Load default value on page load
    updateDropdowns();

    $('#property_type').on('change', function() {
        updateDropdowns();
    });

    $('#myTab2 a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        updateDropdowns();
    });

    function updateDropdowns() {
        var propertyType = $('#property_type').val();
        var selectedTab = $('.tab-content .tab-pane.active').attr("id");

        // Determine the URL for AJAX request based on selected tab
        var ajaxUrl = './conn/are_fetch_data.php';
        var ajaxData = { propertyType: propertyType, tab: selectedTab };

        if (selectedTab === 'rent') {
            // Additional logic if needed for the "rent" tab
            // ajaxUrl = ...
            // ajaxData = ...
        }

        // Send AJAX request to fetch location options
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: ajaxData,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#Locality').html(data);
                $('#Locality').selectpicker('refresh'); // Reinitialize the second dropdown
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Error fetching location options');
            }
        });
    }
});

</script>
```

My concern is if open in buy tab the code is working perfectly, but why is it not working in the rent tab? Why does the data not fetch? Nothing happened in the developer tools.

here is the code my are.fetch_data.php file and everything proper working and also data fetch if the select buy tab but not working rent tab

```
  include 'new_conn.php';

// Retrieve selected property type from AJAX request
$propertyType = $_POST['propertyType'];

// Query the appropriate database table based on property type
if ($propertyType === 'Residential') {
    $tableName = 'residential';
    $columnName = 'R_Locality';
} else {
    $tableName = 'commercial';
    $columnName = 'C_Locality';
}

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT $columnName FROM $tableName";
$result = $conn->query($query);

// Build the options for the area/city dropdown
$options = "<option value=''>Select an Area/City</option>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $options .= "<option value='" . $row[$columnName] . "'>" . $row[$columnName] . "</option>";
}

echo $options;

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: actually i think JavaScript problem or  i think issue in html because if i select buy tab then everything work perfectly but if i am switching rent tab then going to property then data display ok but if i am going to location option then data not show from the table then actually i did not getting where is the problem you can check my code working fine or not

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: I tried to tidy up your description so we can make sense of it, but due to the complete lack of any punctuation or spacing, it was difficult - so apologies if I made any mistakes. Please check it, and edit it further if needed. If you don't write in proper sentences then it makes it very difficult for people to know what you are saying, and it takes a long time to work it out. Please give consideratio to those trying to read your question - it is a piece of written text, not a stream of consciousness on a phone call. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: please check my description carefully i am mentioning everything in details and also upload the screenshot you can easily understand the cod and my problem

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Did you check whether the AJAX request is sent properly? Whether it contains the data you expect?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and/or problem. Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and/or take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

First of all, you have a repeated DOM element `<select class="selectpicker" name="Locality" id="Locality" data-live-search="true">` .

Change that id to `LocalityRent` for example and in your success response depending on which tab you have clicked (rent or buy tab), print your data into that specific DOM element. Every time you are clicking now, as there is a repeated DOM element with the same id, it won't work and it won´t print the response from your PHP code.

You had another element with duplicate id inside your DOM which is `<select class="selectpicker show-tick" name="property_type" id="property_type" >`

I changed both `property_type` to `property_type_rent` and `property_type_buy` respectively.

Each `select` element has to posses its own unique id so that the event listener that is responsible for that action does something specific.

In each case, I added a `dataset.action` to the `select` element so that every time you want to update each dropdown, you can pass the string `buy` or `rent` as a parameter to your AJAX request.

**UPDATED HTML CODE:**

```
 <section class="home-one home1-overlay bg-home1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row posr">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="home_content home1 custom_width">
            <div class="home-text text-center">
              <p class="fz18 color-white">It's great to be Property!</p>
              <h2 class="fz50">Find Your Perfect Property</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="home_tabs">
              <ul class="nav justify-content-center nav-tabs" id="myTab2" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                 <!-- set a dataset.tabId for your button  --> 
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="buy-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-tabId="buy" href="#buy" role="tab" aria-controls="buy" aria-selected="true">Buy</a>
                </li>
                 
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <!-- set a dataset.tabId for your button  --> 
                  <a class="nav-link" id="rent-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-tabId="rent" href="#rent" role="tab" aria-controls="rent" aria-selected="false">Rent</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <!-- test -->
              
              <!-- test -->
              <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent2">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="buy" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="buy-tab">
                  <div class="home_adv_srch_opt">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                      <div class="home_adv_srch_form">
                        <form method="POST" action="a_t_listing.php" class="bgc-white p20" id="searchform" name="searchform">
                          <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md">
                              <div class="form-group style2 mb-2 pl10 pl0-lg">
                                <label>TYPE</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style2-dropdown">
                                  <select class="selectpicker show-tick" name="property_type" id="property_type_buy" data-action="buy" >
                                    <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
                                    <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
                                 
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md">
                              <div class="form-group style2 mb-2 pl10 pl0-lg">
                                <label>LOCATION</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style2-dropdown">
                                  <select class="selectpicker" name="Locality" id="Locality" data-live-search="true">
                                  <!-- <option value="">All Cities / Areas</option> -->
                                  <!-- Data Load By Ajax Best Code Attache footer file -->
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md" style="">
                              <div class="form-group style1 mb-2 ml0-767">
                                <label id="search-lable">SEARCH</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style1-dropdown">
                                  <!-- <select name="searchQuery" class="form-control js-searchBox" id="searchQuery">
                                    <option value="">Endorse Property</option>
                                    <option value="TheBliss">The Bliss</option>
                                    <option value="CasaVyoma">Casa Vyoma</option>
                                    <option value="WorldTradeTower">World Trade Tower</option>
                                    <option value="Hotels">View All Results</option>
                                  </select> -->
                                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery" placeholder="Enter Locality / Project / Society / Landmark" autocomplete="off">
                                  <div id="suggestionContainer"></div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_adv_srch_form_btn mb20-md">
                              <div class="adv_srch_btn dropbtn ml0-767" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop" id="advance_search_mo">
                                <i class="flaticon-setting-lines mr10 mt10 mt0-md flr-520"></i>
                                <span id="advance-search">Advanced Search</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input2" id="home_form_input2">
                               <input type="hidden" name="tab" id="selectedTab" value="buy">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn search-btn ml0-767" id="search-btn"><span class="fa fa-search"></span> Search</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
    
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="rent" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="rent-tab">
                  <div class="home_adv_srch_opt">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                      <div class="home_adv_srch_form">
                        <form method="POST" action="a_t_listing.php" class="bgc-white p20" id="rent-form" name="searchform" >
                          <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md">
                              <div class="form-group style2 mb-2 pl10 pl0-lg">
                                <label>TYPE</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style2-dropdown">
                                  <select class="selectpicker show-tick" name="property_type" id="property_type_rent" data-action="rent" >
                                    <option value="Residentail">Residentail</option>
                                    <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
                                      
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md">
                              <div class="form-group style2 mb-2 pl10 pl0-lg">
                                <label>LOCATION</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style2-dropdown">
                                  <select class="selectpicker" name="Locality" id="LocalityRent" data-live-search="true">
                                  <option value="">All Cities / Areas</option>
                                  <!-- Data Load By Ajax Best Code Attache footer file -->
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input mb15-md">
                              <div class="form-group style1 mb-2 ml0-767">
                                <label>SEARCH</label>
                                <div class="select-wrap style2-dropdown">
                                  <!-- <select name="lang" class="form-control js-searchBox">
                                    <option value="">Endorse Property</option>
                                    <option value="sankalpgrace2">Sankalp Grace 2</option>
                                    <option value="StratumVenus">Stratum Venus</option>
                                    <option value="Indraparasth6">Indraparasth 6</option>
                                    <option value="Hotels">View All Results</option>
                                  </select> -->
                                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery" placeholder="Enter Locality / Project / Society / Landmark" autocomplete="off">
                                  <div id="suggestionContainer"></div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_adv_srch_form_btn mb20-md">
                              <div class="adv_srch_btn dropbtn ml0-767" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
                                <i class="flaticon-setting-lines mr10 mt10 mt0-md flr-520"></i>
                                <span id="advance-search">Advanced Search</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto home_form_input2">
                              <!-- Add a hidden input field to store the selected tab -->
                               <input type="hidden" name="tab" id="selectedTab" value="rent">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn search-btn ml0-767"><span class="fa fa-search"></span> Search</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

    

   <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// Load default value on page load, buy-tab is active
updateDropdowns("buy");

$('#property_type_rent').on('change', function(e) {
    updateDropdowns(e.target.dataset.action);
});

$('#property_type_buy').on('change', function(e) {
    updateDropdowns(e.target.dataset.action);
});


$('#myTab2 a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    updateDropdowns(e.target.dataset.tabId);
});

function updateDropdowns(dataset) {
           var propertyType; 
           if (dataset === 'rent') {
                  propertyType = $('#property_type_rent').val();
              } else {
                 propertyType = $('#property_type_buy').val();
              }

        // Determine the URL for AJAX request based on selected tab
        var ajaxUrl = './conn/are_fetch_data.php';
        var ajaxData = { propertyType: propertyType, tab: dataset };


        // Send AJAX request to fetch location options
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ajaxData
            success: function(data) {
              if (dataset === 'rent') {
                   $('#LocalityRent').html(data);
                   $('#LocalityRent').selectpicker('refresh'); 
              } else {
                   $('#Locality').html(data);
                   $('#Locality').selectpicker('refresh');  
   
              }
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Error fetching location options');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: please check my php code  I mentioned

Comment: if i selected buy tab its working fine without any issue but if the switch rent tab then data not fetching

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your Network tab in Chrome Tools when you click on your rent tab ? A screenshot or a copy from the response that you get from that request. What status does it give you ?

Comment: i am mentioning the screenshot link  please check

Comment: First of all, you have a repeated DOM element  `<select class="selectpicker" name="Locality" id="Locality" data-live-search="true">` . Change that id to `LocalityRent` for example and in your success message depending on which tab you have clicked, print your data into that DOM element.

Comment: if i change only locality Rent id then how to result appear i mean where result display for rent can you please provide the JavaScript full code

Comment: There is no problem with your AJAX request btw. You are getting a 200 status code. Can you also post the response, please ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/vjGc02j       please check the image screenshot after changing the locality rent id but still showing no response. if you don't mind can you come one my any desk

Comment: You haven't posted the response. You are just showing me the request. The response tab is next to your request tab.

Comment: https://ibb.co/1JzZxqg see the response but not working only if i am switching the tab then execute my php file but result not fetching in the dropdown option based on tab change

Comment: You are receiving data on your response as I assumed, the problem is your repeated DOM element as I already told you. It is not possible to have duplicate ids in your DOM.

Comment: https://ibb.co/vwKQc10  see the image i am changing the dropdown id dom id change

Comment: brother can you come on my anydek if possible please. I am troubled since three days but there is no solution

Comment: Try the new updated answer and tell me if that works for you. You had more repeated HTML DOM elements in your code.

Comment: i am updating full code according to your changes code but still no response both condition not working

Comment: There was something I forgot to include in the AJAX. Try it now.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after property listkey:2287:12note: { opened at line 2282, column 15     debugging tools showing this error and also not working both condition

Comment: Tell me your anydesk id.

Comment: this is my id: 250 623 058

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the solution ?